# Making permanent changes to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I apologize if this sounds like an extremely dumb question, but I am trying to learn Python and I can't for the life of me figure this one out. I have some solid experience with other languages but have been stuck on this one for a few days now.

I'm sure the answer is very simple but try as I might, I haven't been able to find any previous threads on the subject.

If it helps, I am using VSCode with Code Runner.

I am playing around with NBA data, using `nba_api.stats`

After calling the api and importing the data as a dataframe, I am building a new dataframe using a subset of the original data.

In:

```py
from nba_api.stats import endpoints
df = data.league_leaders.get_data_frame()

dfTOR = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[df['TEAM'] == 'TOR'])
```

Now, I am trying to modify my new dataframe `dfTOR` by dropping columns, calculating new stats and sorting the data.

In:

```py
for stat in dfTOR[:]:
    if 'PTS' 'FGA' 'REB' 'AST' 'STL' 'BLK' in stat:
        dfTOR = round(dfTOR[:]/dfTOR.GP, 2)

dfTOR = dfTOR.sort_values(by = ['FGA', 'PTS'], ascending = False)

dfTOR = dfTOR.drop(dfTOR.loc[:, 'OREB':'STL_TOV'].columns, axis=1) 
dfTOR = dfTOR.drop(dfTOR.loc[:, 'GP':'FGA'].columns, axis=1)
```

I've tried using different approaches for the things I want to achieve above. But whenever I call `dfTOR` or export it to Excel, none of the changes I've made (it doesn't matter which) are reflected.

In:

```py
print(dfTOR)
dfTOR.to_excel("Raptors.xlsx")
```

I'm sure this is something very basic but I can't figure it out. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

By the way, I've tried using the dataframe.update function but that didn't seem to help either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your expected output, but a lot of the issue are with your syntax.

Here's some changes, and you can play around with it if you'd like.

```
from nba_api.stats import endpoints
import pandas as pd


data = endpoints.leagueleaders.LeagueLeaders() 
df = data.league_leaders.get_data_frame()

dfTOR = pd.DataFrame(df[df['TEAM'] == 'TOR'])



for stat in dfTOR.columns:
    if stat in ['PTS', 'FGA', 'REB', 'AST', 'STL', 'BLK']:
        dfTOR[stat + '_PER_GAME'] = round(dfTOR[stat]/dfTOR.GP, 2)
        

dfTOR = dfTOR.sort_values(by = ['FGA', 'PTS'], ascending = False)

dfTOR = dfTOR.drop(['OREB','STL_TOV'], axis=1) 
dfTOR = dfTOR.drop(['GP','FGA'], axis=1) 

print(dfTOR)
dfTOR.to_excel("Raptors.xlsx")
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for chiming in! This is very helpful and helped me understand how the syntax works, so thank you. I didn't paste the entire code here, so some of it was working, but some was not obviously because of the wrong syntax. I also realized that part of the issue is I had to select everything before running it otherwise it wouldn't run the code as I typed it for some reason. So that one's on me.

Comment: Thanks. Be sure to accept the solution if it fits your needs